# How to search for a string in multiple Stored Procedure Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how specific table is loaded in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.  Is there a way to search through all the Stored Procedure queries?  I can chose to modify each one and search through the query but there are too many to manually search in that fashion.  Any advice in relation to searching for strings in SQL Server Management Studio would be much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(M.object_id), M.*
FROM sys.sql_modules M
JOIN sys.procedures P
ON M.object_id = P.object_id
WHERE M.definition LIKE '%YourTable%'
```

Comment: This may be working... Do you know how to match the object_id to a specific stored procedure?

Comment: @tylercomp - I added the name to my answer

Comment: Awesome, do you know how to match object type as well?

Comment: @tylercomp - Added a JOIN that shows you only the stored procedures.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

Comment: Seems nice, how light is the install?

Comment: @Marc_s - but what is the PRICE?

Comment: @JNK no such thing as a free lunch?

Comment: @tylercomp: two files, less than 20K together - light enough?

Comment: @tylercomp - I'm just giving marc a hard time.

Comment: It's entirely free. The cost for this free lunch is a couple of banner ads below the search results. These are designed to be fairly unintrusive, but of course we'd welcome it if you clicked on the ads!

Answer (score -1):

From [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/list-stored-procedures-sql-server/), I found the following snippet to search through the stored procs:

```
exec sp_stored_procedures 'a%'
OR
exec sp_stored_procedures @sp_name = 'a%'
```

Comment: hmmm, looks like that only returns the names... I am wanting to search the queries for these procedures...